# Regex to find a word between any sequence of number and a word

Tags: regex

I'am trying to find word `<fruit>` the word `color` and `white`  in 
these phrases

**@EDIT Adding more examples**

```
orange: 2 2 7: color he won juice

rice: 1022 2 22: white he won lunch

apple: 1022 2 22: <fruit> he won a banana
```

In my research i found the regex that find a word between two words

```
(?<=apple:\s).*(?=\she)
```

But i am trying use this  regex but  the result is `apple: 1022 2 22: <fruit>` i need find only `<fruit>`

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is your criteria, exactly? Can you add more examples?

Comment: i need find the word <fruit>  in this string above.

Comment: Add a longer sentence which would contain more matches. Currently it seems that you're trying to get the word between `<` and `>`.

Comment: Why do you want to get `<fruit>`? You already have it .. btw https://regex101.com/r/gR7eM4/1

Comment: Exactly, more in a few sentences I have < and > one word specifies a pattern that I will always have is a sequence of numbers like 1 022 2 22: < a word > he or 1 022 2 22:  word he  like this:

`rice: 1022 2 22: white he won lunch

apple: 1022 2 22: <fruit> he won a banana`

Comment: @Shafizadeh i have differents words in sentences differents

Comment: @DaviPereira I see now .. I'm writing an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on updated version of the question, use this pattern:

```
/\d: ([^ ]+)/g
```

And then `$1` contains what you are looking for.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR7eM4/3)

Comment: In this way he always finds the word between the <and> characters more in a few sentences I do not have these characters and need to find the word in the sequence of numbers 121 22 22: and the word "he"

Note: The sequence of numbers can change eg 7 7 2: unlike 121 22 22 more which always keeps the same is the word "he"